# How to filter information in a view by the last week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in Microsoft SQL with tons of information and I would like to create a view which will always show the last 7 days information, based on TODAY's date. This way the user will not have that much information to sort through. DOes anyone perhaps know how to do this?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @codeLover `I have a table in Microsoft SQL`